# Get scanf to quit when it reads a newline?

Tags: c, scanf

If I input `5 5` at the terminal, press enter, and press enter again, I want to exit out of the loop.

```
int readCoefficents(double complex *c){
    int i = 0;
    double real;
    double img;
    while(scanf("%f %f", &real, &img) == 2)
        c[i++] = real + img * I;


    c[i++] = 1 + 0*I; // most significant coefficient is assumed to be 1
    return i;
}
```

Obviously, that code isn't doing the job for me (and yes, I know there is a buffer overflow waiting to happen).

`scanf` won't quit unless I type in a letter (or some non-numeric, not whitespace string). How do I get scanf to quit after reading an empty line?

Comment: In case you needed more reasons to avoid using `scanf`: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use fgets to read console input:

```
   int res = 2;
   while (res == 2) {
       char buf[100];
       fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
       res = sscanf(buf, "%f %f", &real, &img);
       if (res == 2)
           c[i++] = real + img * I;
   }
   c[i++] = 1 + 0*I; // most significant coefficient is assumed to be 1
   return i;
```

Comment: Giving you the credit since you mentioned fgets and sscanf first.

Comment: Thanks, just realised c probably won't let you declare the buffer inside the while loop but the concept is there.

Comment: That declaration is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 10):

The specific problem you're having is that a `scanf` format string of `%f` will skip white space (*including* newlines) until it finds an actual character to scan. From the c99 standard:

> A conversion specification is executed in the following steps:
>      -   Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `'['`, `'c'`, or `'n'` specifier.

and, elsewhere, describing `isspace()`:

> The standard white-space characters are the following: space `' '`, form feed `'\f'`, new-line `'\n'`, carriage return `'\r'`, horizontal tab `'\t'`, and vertical tab `'\v'`.

Your best bet is to use `fgets` to get the line (and this can be protected from buffer overflow very easily), then use `sscanf` on the resultant line.

The `scanf` function is one of those ones you should look at very warily. The following piece of code is one I often use to handle line input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}
```

```
// Test program for getLine().

int main (void) {
    int rc;
    char buff[10];

    rc = getLine ("Enter string> ", buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (rc == NO_INPUT) {
        // Extra NL since my system doesn't output that on EOF.
        printf ("\nNo input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
        printf ("Input too long [%s]\n", buff);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("OK [%s]\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Testing it with various combinations:

```
pax> ./prog
Enter string>[CTRL-D]
No input

pax> ./prog
Enter string> a
OK [a]

pax> ./prog
Enter string> hello
OK [hello]

pax> ./prog
Enter string> hello there
Input too long [hello the]

pax> ./prog
Enter string> i am pax
OK [i am pax]
```

What I would do is to use this function to get a line safely, then simply use:

```
sscanf (buffer, "%f %f", &real, &img)
```

to get the actual values (and check the count).

---

In fact, here's a complete program which is closer to what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}
```

```
int main (void) {
    int i = 1, rc;
    char prompt[50], buff[50];
    float real, imag;

    while (1) {
        sprintf (prompt, "\nEnter real and imaginary for #%3d: ", i);
        rc = getLine (prompt, buff, sizeof(buff));
        if (rc == NO_INPUT) break;
        if (*buff == '\0') break;

        if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
            printf ("** Input too long [%s]...\n", buff);
        }

        if (sscanf (buff, "%f %f", &real, &imag) == 2) {
            printf ("Values were %f and %f\n", real, imag);
            i++;
        } else {
            printf ("** Invalid input [%s]\n", buff);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

along with a test run:

```
pax> ./testprog

Enter real and imaginary for #  1: hello
** Invalid input [hello]

Enter real and imaginary for #  1: hello there
** Invalid input [hello there]

Enter real and imaginary for #  1: 1
** Invalid input [1]

Enter real and imaginary for #  1: 1.23 4.56
Values were 1.230000 and 4.560000

Enter real and imaginary for #  2:

pax> _
```

Comment: +1 Using `scanf` to read input from the user often introduces problems like this.  It is usually much less error-prone to simply read the input as a string and then parse the string.

Answer (score 3):

There's a way to do what you want using just scanf:

```
int readCoefficents(double complex *c) {
    int i = 0;
    double real;
    double img;
    char buf[2];
    while (scanf("%1[\n]", buf) == 0) {         // loop until a blank line or EOF
        if (scanf("%lf %lf", &real, &img) == 2) // read two floats
            c[i++] = real + img * I;
        scanf("%*[^\n]");                       // skip the rest of the line
        scanf("%*1[\n]");                       // and the newline
    }
    c[i++] = 1 + 0*I; // most significant coefficient is assumed to be 1
    return i;
}
```

If the user only enters 1 float on a line, it will read the next line for the second value.  If any random garbage is entered, it will skip up to a newline and try again with the next line.  Otherwise, it will just go on reading pairs of float values until the user enters a blank line or an EOF is reached.

Answer (score 0):

re PAXDIABLO solution: it does not work properly with EMPTY line entered by user, so this line shall be added in your getLine() function

```
if (strlen(buff) <= 1) return NO_INPUT;
```

after the line:

```
if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
    return NO_INPUT;
```

So it will become :

```
...
   if (strlen(buff) <= 1) return NO_INPUT;
   if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL) return NO_INPUT;
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
while(scanf("%f %f", &real, &img) == 2)
```

try

```
while(scanf("%f %f%*c", &real, &img) == 2)


scanf("%f%*c", &myfloat); // will read a float and all eventual characters after it
```