# Sorting Strings in a static array based on their length crashes? |wrong allocation/access|

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, memory-management, c-strings

I wanted to make an array of strings and sort them in order based on their length (smallest -> biggest) but the program crashes after all inputs.
And also it bypasses Element 0 (starts directly from element 1 during input)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    main()
    {
        int i,j,N;
        printf("\nInput amount of  alphanumericals: ");
        scanf("%d",&N);
            {
                int min;
                char *swap=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*150);
                char *A[N],**temp; 
                for(i=0;i<N;i++)
                    *(A+i)=malloc(sizeof(char)*N);//Error Here
                temp=A;
                for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                    printf("\nInput  %d element:",i+1); 
                    fgets(temp+i,150,stdin);//And Here
                }


    printf("\n\nData [");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf(" %s",A[i]);
    printf(" ]\n\n");

    //insertion sort
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        min=i;
        for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){

            if(strcmp(A[j],A[min])<0){
                min=j;
            }

        }   
        if(min!=i){
            swap=A[i];
            A[i]=A[min];
            A[min]=swap;
        }   
    }
    free(swap);
    printf("\n\nInsertion Sorted Data [");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf(" %s",A[i]);
    printf(" ]");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error :

```
 for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    *(A+i)=malloc(sizeof(char)*N);//Error Here
```

i reproduced with g++ compiler, if this is your case also i.e. you also compiling with g++ add casting to char* :

```
*(A+i)= (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*N);//Error Here
```

The second issue is because you trying to pass char** instead of char*
fix :

```
fgets(*(temp+i),150,stdin);//And Here
```

Also brackets after scanf("%d",&N); limits scope of variables ***min*** and ***swap*** , so later should not be visible at all.

Answer (score 1):

First, what happens with element 0: after you enter the number of elements which is read by `scanf("%d")`, you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> so that your input reaches the program. But the `scanf` calls only reads the number, not the newline character. So the first call to `fgets` gets what remains of the line — an empty line.

See [Get scanf to quit when it reads a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723044/get-scanf-to-quit-when-it-reads-a-newline) for several approaches to solve this problem. The most robust way is to call `fgets` to read a line (which is expected to call the number), then call `sscanf` to parse the number in the string in memory.

The second problem is in the call `fgets(temp+i,150,stdin)`. A good compiler would produce a warning like this:

```
a.c:17:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

You're passing a pointer to a pointer to `char` (the address of a location containing the address of a string buffer), but `fgets` expects a pointer to `char` (the address of a string buffer). Since `temp+i` is a pointer to the entry in the array `A` (which is an array of pointers), what you need to pass to `fgets` is the value that this pointer points to: `*(temp+i)`, which is more commonly written `temp[i]`. Given what you do with the variable `temp`, just drop it and use `A`.

```
fgets(A[i], 150, stdin);
```

After that, your sort routing doesn't always return the correct result, but that's another story.

Comment: Could you please indicate to me why sorting algorithm does not working at all times?

Comment: @niCk IIRC I ran it on some sample input and it printed out fewer items than I'd entered. I didn't save the input I used.

Comment: to be exact one input less especially if the input is not even 2,4,... etc right?